# How to dynamically upload image in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

See the code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/SmilePark/pen/yeoqPx)

I want to post the data by form;

There is a add-image button,When I click the button first time and select the image,then show the image info in the page. When I click the button again,then show the two images info in the page.

The problem is: I can't set file value to the `<input type='file' />`

How to do this?

Comment: By security reasons you can't programatically set the value of a `input type='file'` tag. It is not a Vue issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a potential solution [forked from your original codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVvjaQ).

I updated the viewmodel to contain an array of files. The `v-for` renders that array and includes a hidden file input for each item (same as in your code). However, unlike your sample, the file input is not model-bound to the file info. Instead, it calls the `upload()` method whenever its value is changed. The `upload()` method handles updating the underlying file info. With that in place, all the `Add Image` link needs to do is push a new object onto the `files` array and then trigger the click event on that file's input element (after it gets rendered).

Relevant code below.

**Html**

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="file in files">
    <div class="file_item">
      <div class="info">
        <strong>{{file.name}}</strong>
        <p>{{file.size | kb}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="file-{{$index}}" type="file" accept="image/*" @change="upload(file, $event)" style="display:none">
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="value_btn">
  <a href="#" v-on:click="addImage" class="add">
    <span>Add Image</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#item",
  data: {
    files : []       
  },
  methods: {
    addImage: function(){
      this.files.push({ name: "", size: 0})
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            var inputId = "file-" + (this.files.length-1);
            document.getElementById(inputId).click();
        });  
    },
    upload: function(file, e){
      var f = e.target.files[0];
      file.name = f.name;
      file.size = f.size;
    }
  }
})
```